# Is it considered idiomatic to always prefer properties over backing fields?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I recently converted an Android project from Java to Kotlin using Android Studio's Kotlin plugin. Post-conversion, many fields in my classes were highlighted, and hovering over them displays the message

> This property has a backing field

[image: Android Studio screenshot showing hover message]

Should I infer from the existence of this message/warning that it is always considered more idiomatic (in Kotlin) to use properties with explicitly-defined getters and/or setters? Or is the IDE being a little over-zealous with the informational messages? Answers that include references to official sources preferred :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Idiomatic is to use properties without backing properties.  Backing properties are an exception case, as are custom getters and setters. You do need to be aware of the difference between a "Backing Field" and "Backing Property":

In the Kotlin docs, it talks about [Backing Fields](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-fields) which are something you sometimes access from custom getters/setters and exist for any given property.  There is an implied name for backing fields of `field`, so in a setter you would access this backing field by that name:

```
var counter = 0 // the initializer value is written directly to the backing field
  set(value) {
    if (value >= 0)
      field = value
  }
```

A [Backing Property](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-properties) on the other hand is something that you define to store the value in another private property and of which you have complete control over.  By convention it would be `private` and be prefixed with an underscore `_`.  This looks like:

```
private var _table: Map<String, Int>? = null

public val table: Map<String, Int>
  get() {
    if (_table == null)
      _table = HashMap() // Type parameters are inferred
    return _table ?: throw AssertionError("Set to null by another thread")
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Nothing to worry about, it's a known issue with the IDE. The highlighting is there simply for your information, cause backing fields require some extra care in certain cases.

If it troubles you, just turn the inspection off. Or change the highlighting to be not so bright.

Comment: Thanks! I turned off the highlighting, which also seemed to turn off the info message shown on hover (I could not find a separate inspection or intention to explicitly disable).

Comment: I believe it is just bad background color for such fields. Changing it to a darker one would make it look better and stop annoying.

Comment: @SergeyMashkov agree, the color is intense; I just wasn't sure if there was a 'deeper meaning' behind the intensity!